# Why is my onBackup() method for my BackupAgentHelper not being called?

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I've read through the documentation and other questions, but I guess I'm missing something. My BackupAgent's `onCreate` is being called, but not its `onBackup`, even when I call `adb bmgr backup <package>` and then `adb shell bmgr run` from command line. What part of the equation am I missing?

MyBackupAgent class:

```
public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper {

    public MyBackupAgent() {
        Log.d("GradeTracker.MyBackupAgent", "onCreate called");
        String str = DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME;
        FileBackupHelper myDb = new FileBackupHelper(this, "../databases/" + str);
        addHelper(DBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME , myDb);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data,
         ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {

        Log.d("GradeTracker.MyBackupAgent", "onBackup called");

            synchronized (DBAdapter.dbBackupLockObject) {
                    super.onBackup(oldState, data, newState);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestore(BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode,
                    ParcelFileDescriptor newState) throws IOException {

            Log.d("GradeTracker.MyBackupAgent", "onRestore called");

            synchronized (DBAdapter.dbBackupLockObject) {
                    super.onRestore(data, appVersionCode, newState);
            }
    }
}
```

In my Manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:backupAgent="MyBackupAgent"
...
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key" 
            android:value="<my_key>" />
```

I only registered my app with Android Backup Services a few hours ago, but it didn't say I'd have to wait. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code I thought I was running in `onCreate()` I was actually running in the constructor. I don't even have an onCreate. >.<

Answer (score 0):

It seems that log entries from BackupAgent don't show up in the log. However, you can create a breakpoint and the execution stops in `onBackup()` while debugging.